# Bad behaving particles

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, particles

I found great tutorial from Tutor4u:

[Blender Beyond Basics #4: Fun with Transformations - Blender Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4k7zClCcE8)

But somehow I end to odd results with that. Here I have five different frames:

[image]

As you can see, the particles become already visible on the frames 48 and 49, but then suddenly the original torus is seen on frames 50, 51 and 52, until on frame 53 it is again as expected. These are just few examples. The issue continues during the animation.

If I do the manual rendering on those frames, they are seen as expected. So this problem appears only during the rendering the animation.

- File format: FFMpeg
- Video Container: MPEG-4
- Video codec: H.264
- Rendering engine: Cycles
- Rendering sampling: 24

Is this a bug which should be reported into somewhere or what do you think, and have you seen similar issues?

Comment: can you please provide blend file?

Comment: @chris here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jZub0FdNrHffNZSfA2_Oe88qau2mnkqs?usp=sharing

Comment: And I need to say also, I'm using Blender 2.92 version. I do AMD GPU.